# Save on FCM database message's timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I'm using the follow steps from the tutorial in order to understant fcm and I'm wondering if there is anyway to save the timestamp from the send/recieved messages?

[Google FCM Tutorial Page 8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#7)

```
 this.messagesRef.push({
      name: currentUser.displayName,
      text: this.messageInput.value,
      photoUrl: currentUser.photoURL || '/images/profile_placeholder.png'
    })
```

As you can see on this sample code I push name, text and photoUrl but I want also the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getTime() method, it returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

**time: new Date().getTime()**

Sample Code:

```
this.messagesRef.push({
   name: currentUser.displayName,
   text: this.messageInput.value,
   photoUrl: currentUser.photoURL || '/images/profile_placeholder.png',
   time: new Date().getTime()
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why I couldn't find this method? If possible post the link where you find this method and possibly other

Comment: @Nick This is  a javascript datetime method. Just refer the following link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp